# How to add a default control action to the smart home device that will be visible and clickable in Google Home app?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I created a "Smart home" action that controls my [Door](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/door) device with [OpenClose](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/openclose) trait. This device was added to the Google Home app and now I can control it using google assistant by voice: "*Ok Google, open the door*".

How can I add an "Open" control action to be visible under my Door device in the Google Home app that allow me to click on it to send open command? I would like it to be similar to light device that has "Turn On"/"Turn off" based on current state of the light.

[image: Google App Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The [platform touch controls](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls) are not something that a developer can modify, so there is no way for you to add a button to open or close your door.